# I want to replace every value in the age column with its middle value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column that looks like this:

```
Age
[0-10)
[10-20)
[20-30)
[30-40)
[40-50)
[50-60)
[60-70)
[70-80)
```

and want to remove the "[","-" and ")". Instead of showing the range such as 0-10, I would like to show the middle value instead for every row in the column

Comment: Can you share an example of what you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 4):

Yet another solution:

The dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':['[0-10)','[10-20)','[20-30)','[30-40)','[40-50)','[50-60)','[60-70)','[70-80)']})
df
       Age
0    [0-10)
1   [10-20)
2   [20-30)
3   [30-40)
4   [40-50)
5   [50-60)
6   [60-70)
7   [70-80)
```

The code:

```
df['Age'] = df.Age.str.extract('(\d+)-(\d+)').astype('int').mean(axis=1).astype('int')
```

The result:

```
df

    Age
0     5
1    15
2    25
3    35
4    45
5    55
6    65
7    75
```

Comment: For me this is the right solution. +1. But take care of the last `astype(int)`. It's possible to raise an exception if the result is `xx.5`. Or use `round(0)` before. Or simply let the result as float.

Comment: Oh,  thank you, good point. I was not sure if Vish would be ok using float values, but I would also ignore that last astype(int).

Comment: @Corralien, I tested the solution forcing a float result and then applied the astype(int) method. Pandas rounds down the value, transforming the float into an int, so, I believe we are good.

Comment: Indeed, `astype(int)` returns the ceiling of the float. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explode a row into multiple rows where each row carries a value from the range, you can do this:

```
data = '''[0-10)
[10-20)
[20-30)
[30-40)
[40-50)
[50-60)
[60-70)
[70-80)'''

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': data.splitlines()})

df['Age'] = df['Age'].str.extract(r'\[(\d+)-(\d+)\)').astype(int).apply(lambda r: list(range(r[0], r[1])), axis=1)

df.explode('Age')
```

Note that I assume your `Age` column is string typed, so I used `extract` to get the boundaries of the ranges, and convert them to a real list of integers. Finally explode your dataframe for the modified Age column will get you a new row for each integer in the list. Values in other columns will be copied accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {
    'age_range': [
        '[0-10)',
        '[10-20)',
        '[20-30)',
        '[30-40)',
        '[40-50)',
        '[50-60)',
        '[60-70)',
        '[70-80)',
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

def get_middle_age(age_range):
    pattern = r'(\d+)'
    ages = re.findall(pattern, age_range)

    return int((int(ages[0])+int(ages[1]))/2)

df['age'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_middle_age(row['age_range']), axis=1)
```